# How to run any groups method specific to any class in selenium?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

How to run any groups method specific to any class in selenium?

suppose i have 100 of class and i only want to run any groups method for which there is groups exist of same name in that class and it should not run for all classes, which has not group of that name

I have created all common method in one septate class.

Answer (score 0):

Say if your Java class like below,

```
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class UnitLevelTesting {    

    @Test(groups={"feature1","feature2"})
    public void unitTest1() {
        System.out.println("Unit test1");
    }

    @Test(groups="feature1")
    public void unitTest2() {
        System.out.println("Unit test2");
    }

    @Test(groups="feature2")
    public void unitTest3() {
        System.out.println("Unit test2");
    }
}
```

Your Class B

```
import org.testng.annotations.Test;


public class FunctionalTesting {
    @Test(groups="feature1")t
    public void scenario1() {
        System.out.println("Scenario1");
    }

    @Test
    public void scenario2() {
        System.out.println("Scenario2");
    }

    @Test(groups="feature2")
    public void scenario3() {
        System.out.println("Scenario3");
    }
}
```

Then your Suite file should be,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<suite name="Suite">
    <test name="feauture1">
        <groups>
            <run>
                <include name="feature1" />
                <exclude name="feature2" />
            </run>
        </groups>
        <classes>
            <class name="com.javarticles.testng.UnitLevelTesting" />
            <class name="com.javarticles.testng.FunctionalTesting" />
        </classes>
    </test>   
</suite>
```